# Difference between IEnumable and IQueryable "Where" clause in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

I am a little confused about the underlying mechanism in the FindBy and FindByExp functions below. I understand that FindyByExp will execute the predicate at the database side. But how about the FindBy function? Does it get all the objects from the database and load them into memory first, and then execute the predicate?

```
    public IQueryable<T> FindBy(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return context.Get<T>().Where(predicate).AsQueryable<T>();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> FindByExp(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return context.Get<T>().Where(predicate).AsQueryable<T>();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FindBy` would get *all*  `T` objects from the database and filter them in memory in your program when you enumerate the result.

`FindByExp` would change the query that gets executed on the database server and add the where clause.